# calling external process from c# flaky behaviour

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, impersonation

New challenge. I execute an external process from an ASP page. I impersonate a user with `processstartinfo`. I am logged in with the same user, so I can see the process (cmdshell) interactively.

What I notice is that every now and then the execution stalls for a while, and then moves on. When I run the process from my console (same user as the impersonated one), the execution runs smooth.

Anyone expriences something like this or knows how to troubleshoot this kinda behavior.

Any info welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, stupid old executable with impossible std out redirection